# What I should do before publish my app

Tags: android, google-play

- What I have to change in build.gradle file and AndroidManifest before I publish? Some variables are created together with project, and came with a default value, like minifyEnabled false (in build.gradle) or android:supportsRtl="true" (in  AndroidManifest). Should I change some thoses before I publish (to release version)?
- And I was wondering too when a user buy a pro version, what ensures that she/he doesn't go to take the .apk file and gives to someone else? I have to do   something in my code to Android delete this .apk on user device?
- And my last question is about the keystore, what is better: Sign all my apps with the same keystore or create a new one to each app?

Variables that I found in these files

build.gradle (project)

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

build.gradle (module:app)

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

and

AndroidManifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        ...>
```

Should I change some those to release version?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You don't need to change `minifyEnabled` and `android:supportsRtl`.
   *`minifyEnabled`* is used to define that code obfuscation needed or not. supportSrtl define that your app support right-to-left (RTL) layouts. So both of them are not related to release version they are dependent on your code and need whether you need them in your app or not.
2. If you added google in-app-purchase system in your App then backup Apps don't consider as a paid App, they are just new app which are downloaded without Internet. [Link](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/index.html)
3. It depends how you manage your keys, its same like set same pin for your all social networking sites or set different.

Comment: These are good advices but not enough. I would rather suggest to follow the Google official checklist before publishing your app. [Here](https://developer.android.com/distribute/tools/launch-checklist.html)

Comment: Yeah @GVillani82 agree, I also suggest Anita to verify checklist but I tried to resolve queries which were asked.

Comment: Really thanks, just one more thing, if minifyEnabled is used to define code obfuscation, then It would not be better if it was true, this way the code will be more protected, won't be? And thanks too @GVillani82 this link really helped me. :)

Comment: If minifyEnabled = true then your code is more secure